# Expand data.frame by creating duplicates based on group condition (2)

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, grouping, addition

Starting from @AndrewGustar answer/code: [Expand data.frame by creating duplicates based on group condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44239415/expand-data-frame-by-creating-duplicates-based-on-group-condition)

1)
What about if I have the input data.frame with `ID` values not in sequence and that can also duplicate theirselves?

Example data.frame:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID  Day Count   Count_group
18  1933    6   11
33  1933    6   11
37  1933    6   11
18  1933    6   11
16  1933    6   11
11  1933    6   11
111 1932    5   8
34  1932    5   8
60  1932    5   8
88  1932    5   8
18  1932    5   8
33  1931    3   4
13  1931    3   4
56  1931    3   4
23  1930    1   1
6   1800    6   10
37  1800    6   10
98  1800    6   10
52  1800    6   10
18  1800    6   10
76  1800    6   10
55  1799    4   6
6   1799    4   6
52  1799    4   6
133 1799    4   6
112 1798    2   2
677 1798    2   2
778 888     4   6
111 888     4   6
88  888     4   6
10  888     4   6
37  887     2   3
26  887     2   3
8   886     1   2
56  885     1   1', header = TRUE)
```

The `Count` col shows the total number of `ID` values per each `Day` and the `Count_group` col shows the sum of the `ID` values per each `Day` and `Day - 1`.

e.g. 1933 = `Count_group` 11 because `Count` 6 (1933) + `Count` 5 (1932), and so on.

What I need to do is to create duplicated observations per each `Count_group` and add them to it in order to show per each `Count_group` its `Day` AND `Day - 1`.

e.g. `Count_group` = 11 is composed by the `Count` values of `Day` 1933 and 1932. So both days needs to be included in the `Count_group` = 11. The next one will be `Count_group` = 8, composed by 1932 and 1931, etc...

Desired output:

```
    ID  Day   Count Count_group
    18  1933    6   11
    33  1933    6   11
    37  1933    6   11
    18  1933    6   11
    16  1933    6   11
    11  1933    6   11
    111 1932    5   11
    34  1932    5   11
    60  1932    5   11
    88  1932    5   11
    18  1932    5   11
    111 1932    5   8
    34  1932    5   8
    60  1932    5   8
    88  1932    5   8
    18  1932    5   8
    33  1931    3   8
    13  1931    3   8
    56  1931    3   8
    33  1931    3   4
    13  1931    3   4
    56  1931    3   4
    23  1930    1   4
    23  1930    1   1
    6   1800    6   10
    37  1800    6   10
    98  1800    6   10
    52  1800    6   10
    18  1800    6   10
    76  1800    6   10
    55  1799    4   10
    6   1799    4   10
    52  1799    4   10
    133 1799    4   10
    55  1799    4   6
    6   1799    4   6
    52  1799    4   6
    133 1799    4   6
    112 1798    2   6
    677 1798    2   6
    112 1798    2   2
    677 1798    2   2
    778 888     4   6
    111 888     4   6
    88  888     4   6
    10  888     4   6
    37  887     2   6
    26  887     2   6
    37  887     2   3
    26  887     2   3
    8   886     1   3
    8   886     1   2
    56  885     1   2
    56  885     1   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that keeps the ID values as above.

```
#first add grouping variables
df$smalldaygroup <- c(0,cumsum(sapply(2:nrow(df),function(i) df$Day[i]!=df$Day[i-1]))) #individual days
df$bigdaygroup <- c(0,cumsum(sapply(2:nrow(df),function(i) df$Day[i]<df$Day[i-1]-1))) #blocks of consecutive days

#duplicate individual days except the first in each big group
df2 <- lapply(split(df,df$bigdaygroup),function(x) 
  split(x,x$smalldaygroup)[c(1,rep(2:length(split(x,x$smalldaygroup)),each=2))])

#change the Count_group to previous value in alternate entries
df2 <- lapply(df2,function(L) lapply(1:length(L),function(i) {
  x <- L[[i]]
  if(!(i%%2)) x$Count_group <- L[[i-1]]$Count_group[1]
  return(x)
}))

df2 <- do.call(rbind,unlist(df2,recursive=FALSE)) #bind back together

head(df2,20) #ignore rownames!
       ID  Day Count Count_group
01.1   18 1933     6          11
01.2   33 1933     6          11
01.3   37 1933     6          11
01.4   18 1933     6          11
01.5   16 1933     6          11
01.6   11 1933     6          11
02.7  111 1932     5          11
02.8   34 1932     5          11
02.9   60 1932     5          11
02.10  88 1932     5          11
02.11  18 1932     5          11
03.7  111 1932     5           8
03.8   34 1932     5           8
03.9   60 1932     5           8
03.10  88 1932     5           8
03.11  18 1932     5           8
04.12  33 1931     3           8
04.13  13 1931     3           8
04.14  56 1931     3           8
05.12  33 1931     3           4
```

Comment: Hi, with my real data.frame I get this error after doing do.call: Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match

Comment: I don't know why! my real data.frame looks identical to my example one!

Comment: The `do.call` error might be caused by some `NA`s or missing data.  You could try replacing this line with `df2 <- unlist(df2,recursive=FALSE); df2 <- df2[sapply(df2,length)==6]; df2 <- do.call(rbind,df2)`.

Comment: new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44247395/expand-data-frame-by-creating-duplicates-based-on-group-condition-3 thanks