# Expand data.frame by creating duplicates based on group condition (3)

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, rows

Starting from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242299/expand-data-frame-by-creating-duplicates-based-on-group-condition-2).

Example `data.frame`:

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID  Day Count   Count_group
            18  1933    6   15
            33  1933    6   15
            37  1933    6   15
            18  1933    6   15
            16  1933    6   15
            11  1933    6   15
            111 1932    5   9
            34  1932    5   9
            60  1932    5   9
            88  1932    5   9
            18  1932    5   9
            33  1931    3   4
            13  1931    3   4
            56  1931    3   4
            23  1930    1   1
            6   1800    6   12
            37  1800    6   12
            98  1800    6   12
            52  1800    6   12
            18  1800    6   12
            76  1800    6   12
            55  1799    4   6
            6   1799    4   6
            52  1799    4   6
            133 1799    4   6
            112 1798    2   2
            677 1798    2   2
            778 888     4   8
            111 888     4   8
            88  888     4   8
            10  888     4   8
            37  887     2   4
            26  887     2   4
            8   886     1   2
            56  885     1   1
            22  120     2   6
            34  120     2   6
            88  119     1   6
            99  118     2   5
            12  118     2   5
            90  117     1   3
            22  115     2   2
            99  115     2   2', header = TRUE)
```

The `Count` col shows the total number of `ID` values per each `Day` and the `Count_group` col shows the sum of the `ID` values per each `Day`, `Day - 1`, `Day -2`, `Day -3` and `Day -4`.

e.g. 1933 = `Count_group` 15 because `Count` 6 (1933) + `Count` 5 (1932) + `Count` 3 (1931) + `Count` 1 (1930) + `Count` 0 (1929).

What I need to do is to create duplicated observations per each `Count_group` and add them to it in order to show per each `Count_group` its `Day`, `Day - 1`, `Day -2`, `Day -3` and `Day -4`.

e.g. `Count_group` = 15 is composed by the Count values of `Day` 1933, 1932, 1931, 1930 (and 1929 not present in the `df`). So the five days needs to be included in the `Count_group` = 15. The next one will be `Count_group` = 9, composed by 1932, 1931, 1930, 1929 and 1928; etc...

Desired output:

```
ID  Day   Count Count_group
18  1933    6   15
33  1933    6   15
37  1933    6   15
18  1933    6   15
16  1933    6   15
11  1933    6   15
111 1932    5   15
34  1932    5   15
60  1932    5   15
88  1932    5   15
18  1932    5   15
33  1931    3   15
13  1931    3   15
56  1931    3   15
23  1930    1   15

111 1932    5   9
34  1932    5   9
60  1932    5   9
88  1932    5   9
18  1932    5   9
33  1931    3   9
13  1931    3   9
56  1931    3   9
23  1930    1   9

33  1931    3   4
13  1931    3   4
56  1931    3   4
23  1930    1   4

23  1930    1   1

6   1800    6   12
37  1800    6   12
98  1800    6   12
52  1800    6   12
18  1800    6   12
76  1800    6   12
55  1799    4   12
6   1799    4   12
52  1799    4   12
133 1799    4   12
112 1798    2   12
677 1798    2   12

55  1799    4   6
6   1799    4   6
52  1799    4   6
133 1799    4   6
112 1798    2   6
677 1798    2   6

112 1798    2   2
677 1798    2   2

778 888     4   8
111 888     4   8
88  888     4   8
10  888     4   8
37  887     2   8
26  887     2   8
8   886     1   8
56  885     1   8

37  887     2   4
26  887     2   4
8   886     1   4
56  885     1   4

8   886     1   2
56  885     1   2

56  885     1   1

22  120     2   6
34  120     2   6
88  119     1   6
99  118     2   6
12  118     2   6
90  117     1   6

88  119     1   6
99  118     2   6
12  118     2   6
90  117     1   6
22  115     2   6
99  115     2   6

99  118     2   5
12  118     2   5
90  117     1   5
22  115     2   5
99  115     2   5

90  117     1   3
22  115     2   3
99  115     2   3

22  115     2   2
99  115     2   2
```

(note that different group of 5 days each one have been separated by a blank line in order to make them clearer)

I have got different data.frames which are grouped by n days and therefore I would like to adapt the code (by changing it a little) specifically for each of them.

Thanks

Comment: Question updated with new df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalised version of my previous answer...

```
#first add grouping variables
days <- 5 #grouping no of days
df$smalldaygroup <- c(0,cumsum(sapply(2:nrow(df),function(i) df$Day[i]!=df$Day[i-1]))) #individual days
df$bigdaygroup <- c(0,cumsum(sapply(2:nrow(df),function(i) df$Day[i]<df$Day[i-1]-days+1))) #blocks of linked days

#duplicate days in each big group
df2 <- lapply(split(df,df$bigdaygroup),function(x) {
  n <- max(x$Day)-min(x$Day)+1 #number of consecutive days in big group
  dayvec <- (max(x$Day):min(x$Day)) #possible days in range
  daylog <- dayvec[dayvec %in% x$Day] #actual days in range
  pattern <- data.frame(base=rep(dayvec,each=days))
  pattern$rep <- sapply(1:nrow(pattern),function(i) pattern$base[i]+1-sum(pattern$base[1:i]==pattern$base[i])) #indices to repeat
  pattern$offset <- match(pattern$rep,daylog)-match(pattern$base,daylog) #offsets (used later)
  pattern <- pattern[(pattern$base %in% x$Day) & (pattern$rep %in% x$Day),] #remove invalid elements
  #store pattern in list as offsets needed in next loop
  return(list(df=split(x,x$smalldaygroup)[match(pattern$rep,daylog)],pat=pattern))
})

#change the Count_group to previous value in added entries
df2 <- lapply(df2,function(L) lapply(1:length(L$df),function(i) {
  x <- L$df[[i]]
  offset <- L$pat$offset #pointer to day to copy Count_group from
  x$Count_group <- L$df[[i-offset[i]]]$Count_group[1]
  return(x)
}))

df2 <- do.call(rbind,unlist(df2,recursive=FALSE)) #bind back together

df2[,5:6] <- NULL #remove grouping variables

head(df2,30) #ignore rownames!

       ID  Day Count Count_group
01.1   18 1933     6          15
01.2   33 1933     6          15
01.3   37 1933     6          15
01.4   18 1933     6          15
01.5   16 1933     6          15
01.6   11 1933     6          15
02.7  111 1932     5          15
02.8   34 1932     5          15
02.9   60 1932     5          15
02.10  88 1932     5          15
02.11  18 1932     5          15
03.12  33 1931     3          15
03.13  13 1931     3          15
03.14  56 1931     3          15
04     23 1930     1          15
05.7  111 1932     5           9
05.8   34 1932     5           9
05.9   60 1932     5           9
05.10  88 1932     5           9
05.11  18 1932     5           9
06.12  33 1931     3           9
06.13  13 1931     3           9
06.14  56 1931     3           9
07     23 1930     1           9
08.12  33 1931     3           4
08.13  13 1931     3           4
08.14  56 1931     3           4
09     23 1930     1           4
010    23 1930     1           1
11.16   6 1800     6          12
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Will this work with any grouping condition of n days? I can't check it right now..

Comment: Yes, it should do, although I've not checked it for days>3.  Needed a bit more thought, this one!

Comment: (If you fancy) Here another question on how to add an index col based on the Count_group one https://stackoverflow.com/q/44250468/7249029

Comment: That is just `bigdaygroup` as above, I think

Comment: Hi, I just realised that your code does not work 100% with my real data.frame. I updated my question with a new example data.frame and example output based on a 5-day window (but still need to apply the code to n time window). could you please have a look? thanks

Comment: The only case it doesn't work for is the last group where you don't have a consecutive group of days - there is no day 116.  To solve it, just redefine the definition of `bigdaygroup` as amended above (line 2).

Comment: hi, thank you. but it does not work..just compare my expected output with yours.

Comment: Edited version above.  Not quite as straightforward as I thought!

Comment: thanks..it seems ok. can I still apply the code to different time windows?

Comment: here a question on how to index the above dataset https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336511/group-rows-and-create-index-column-based-on-ranking

Comment: Glad this one works!  It should work for other time windows - just change the value of `days` in the first line.

Comment: @aaaaa Thanks for the bounty! Much appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145777/discussion-between-aaaaa-and-andrew-gustar).

Answer (score 1):

I attach a rather mechanical method, but I believe it is a good starting point.
I have noticed that in your original table the entry

`ID  Day   Count Count_group
18  1933     6     14`

is duplicated; I have left it untouched for sake of clarity.

Structure of the approach:

1. Read original data
2. Generate list of data frames, for each `Day`
3. Generate final data frame, collapsing the list in 2.

### 1. Read original data

We start with

```
df = read.table(text = 'ID  Day Count   Count_group
                18  1933    6   14
                33  1933    6   14
                37  1933    6   14
                18  1933    6   14
                16  1933    6   14
                11  1933    6   14
                111 1932    5   9
                34  1932    5   9
                60  1932    5   9
                88  1932    5   9
                18  1932    5   9
                33  1931    3   4
                13  1931    3   4
                56  1931    3   4
                23  1930    1   1
                6   1800    6   12
                37  1800    6   12
                98  1800    6   12
                52  1800    6   12
                18  1800    6   12
                76  1800    6   12
                55  1799    4   6
                6   1799    4   6
                52  1799    4   6
                133 1799    4   6
                112 1798    2   2
                677 1798    2   2
                778 888     4   7
                111 888     4   7
                88  888     4   7
                10  888     4   7
                37  887     2   4
                26  887     2   4
                8   886     1   2
                56  885     1   1', header = TRUE)

# ordered vector of unique values for "Day"
ord_day <- unique(df$Day[order(df$Day)])
ord_day
 [1]  885  886  887  888 1798 1799 1800 1930 1931 1932 1933
```

### 2. Generate list of data frames, for each `Day`

For each element in `ord_day` we introduce a data.frame as element of a list called `df_new_aug`.
Such data frames are defined through a `for` loop for all values in `ord_day` except `ord_day[2]` and `ord_day[1]` which are treated separately.

Idea behind the looping: for each unique `ord_day[i]` with `i > 2` we check which days between `ord_day[i-1]` and `ord_day[i-2]` (or both!) contribute (through the variable `"Count"`) to the value `"Count_Group"` at `ord_day[i]`.

We therefore introduce `if else` statements in the loop.
Here we go

```
# Recursive generation of the list of data.frames (for days > 886)
#-----------------------------------------------------------------
df_new <- list()
df_new_aug <- list()

# we exclude cases  i=1, 2: they are manually treated below
for ( i in 3: length(ord_day) ) {

  # is "Count_Group" for ord_day[i] equal to the sum of "Count" at ord_day[i-1] and ord_day[i-2]?
  if ( unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], "Count_group"]) == unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], "Count"])  +  
       unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i-1], "Count"]) + unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i-2], "Count"])
       ) {

        # we create columns ID | Day | Count
        df_new[[i]] <- data.frame(df[df$Day == ord_day[i] | df$Day == ord_day[i-1] | df$Day == ord_day[i-2], 
                                     c("ID", "Day", "Count")])

        # we append the Count_Group of the Day in ord_day[i]
        df_new_aug[[i]] <- data.frame( df_new[[i]],
                                   Count_group = rep(unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], "Count_group"]), nrow(df_new[[i]]) ) )


         } else if (unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], "Count_group"]) == unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], "Count"])  +  
                    unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i-1], "Count"]) ) #only "Count" at i and i-1 contribute to "Count_group" at i
                    {

                    df_new[[i]] <- data.frame(df[df$Day == ord_day[i] | df$Day == ord_day[i-1], 
                                                 c("ID", "Day", "Count")])

                    # we append the Count_Group of the Day in ord_day[2]
                    df_new_aug[[i]] <- data.frame(df_new[[i]],
                                                  Count_group = rep(unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], "Count_group"]), nrow(df_new[[i]]) ) )

                     } else #only "Count" at i contributes to "Count_group" at i

                            df_new[[i]] <- data.frame(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], 
                                                         c("ID", "Day", "Count")])

                            # we append the Count_Group of the Day in ord_day[i]
                            df_new_aug[[i]] <- data.frame(df_new[[i]],
                                                          Count_group = rep(unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[i], "Count_group"]), nrow(df_new[[i]]) ) )


  #closing the for loop     
  }


# for ord_day[2] = "886" (both "Count" at i =2 and i = 1 contribute to "Count_group" at i=2)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
df_new[[2]] <- data.frame(df[df$Day == ord_day[2] | df$Day == ord_day[1], 
                             c("ID", "Day", "Count")])

# we append the Count_Group of the Day in ord_day[2]
df_new_aug[[2]] <- data.frame(df_new[[2]],
                              Count_group = rep(unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[2], "Count_group"]), nrow(df_new[[2]]) ) )

# for ord_day[1] = "885" (only "count" at i = 1 contributes to "Count_group" at i =1)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
df_new[[1]] <- data.frame(df[df$Day == ord_day[1], c("ID", "Day", "Count")])

# we append the Count_Group of the Day in ord_day[i]
df_new_aug[[1]] <- data.frame(df_new[[1]], Count_group = rep(unique(df[df$Day == ord_day[1], "Count_group"]), nrow(df_new[[1]]) ) )


# produced list
df_new_aug
```

### 3. Generate final data frame, collapsing the list in 2.

We collapse `df_new_aug` through an ugly loop, but other solutions (for example with `Reduce()` and `merge()` are possible):

```
# merging the list (mechanically): final result
df_result <- df_new_aug[[1]]
for (i in 1:10){
  df_result <- rbind(df_result, df_new_aug[[i+1]])      
}
```

One arrives at `df_result` and the analysis is stopped.